# ASP.net upload fails for files with large size

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have created a simple movie website with ASP.net, but it only accepts small-sized files for uploads. The code looks like this (this part is just under the upload click event):

```
HttpPostedFile file = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
// Saving Files on Local folder
file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Videos/") + file.FileName);
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["constr"];
connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO movieTable(Title,UploadDate)VALUES (@filme,@mydatetime)", connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filme", FileUpload1.FileName);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@mydatetime", DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

When I try to upload a large video file, it gives me an `access denied` error. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: on which line does it error on?  can you capture the error?  If so please edit your question and post it within it.  It will help us track it down.

Comment: Is the videos folder writeable by the account your apps runs as, probably NetworkService?

Comment: the error is comes from the google page , says " This page is not available "  .But when i try to upload small size of video file , it is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Your server may have a limit on the size of files it can accept for uploading.

Apparently, there is a 4MB default limit set in `machine.config`, but you can override it in you `web.config`. For example, this increases the upload limit to 20MB:

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="20480" />
</system.web>
```

You can read more about [large file uploads in ASP.NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/08/large-file-uploads-in-asp-net.aspx).

Comment: the macRequestLength is :  65535 , but still makes problem

Comment: Do you mean `maxRequestLength`? AFAIK, `maxRequestLength` controls the acceptable size of input from the client-side (browsers), but it doesn't affect the server's file upload limitation. Try changing the server setting as well.